# Remove form input field when clear button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, polymer, dom-events

I have added the following function to simply remove a field when clear button is clicked. The err I am getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

To fix that I tried to add the class `positionInput` inside the div for the input field;that didn't fix it of course.

```
_clear() {
  var newPosition = document.getElementById("position");
  newPosition.classList.remove("positionInput");
}
```

Here is the object that injects the new form input field:

```
_addPosition(e) {

   let newPosition = document.createElement('input');               
   newPosition.classList = 'positionInput';                
   positionGroup.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newPosition);
}
```

And here is the markup for input filed and clear button

```
 <div style="display: flex; margin: 0.5em 0 1em 0;">
    <input style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button" value="SAVE" on-click="_post" />
    <input type="button" value="CLEAR" on-click="_clear" />
</div>
```

Comment: I should add the html for input field as well: <div>
<input style="display: block;" type="text" id="position" name="position" placeholder="*Position" value="{{_contact.position::input}}">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with input type reset, or  reset function on clear button